# Highcharts (highstock) anyway to detect maximum value in a series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

As you know Highcharts automagically calculate the max and min for yAxis unless you specifically set something like `yAxis: { min: 0, max: 100}`.

However in my case, I am not always sure what the max of my data is going to be, and I wanted to set the `yAxis.max` to whatever value that is largest in my dataset that is loaded.

A workaround I come up with now is to export a `yMax` from backend and then use `setExtremes(0, yMax)` on the frontend to make this happen. But given highchart's high performance and automagic nature, is it possible to complete this operation solely from the frontend?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you seen `getExtremes()`?  http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.getExtremes

Comment: yAxisOptions is an array based on this function getAxes in highcharts.js. You may have a look at this function

Comment: @wf4 I thought `getExtremes()` only gets the extremes of the current plot area, is it not? For example: http://jsfiddle.net/0djqzjhr/

Comment: no, you can use `dataMin` and `dataMax` to get the data values http://jsfiddle.net/0djqzjhr/1/

Comment: @wf4 yes, but if you scroll the scrollbar a little bit to the left you will see data points with value 500 and above, and that's what I meant to get -- not just the max value shown in the current plot area, but the whole series.

Comment: aha, good point. I'm not sure on that one I'm afraid. Not sure if something like this would help?  You could attach a redraw event to the chart and get the new values as you scroll like this. http://jsfiddle.net/0djqzjhr/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by scanning you data in the events.load:

```
events: {
    load: function () {
        var points = []
        this.series.forEach(function (entry) {
            entry.data.forEach(function (theData) {
                points.push(theData.y);
            });
        });
        this.yAxis[0].update({
            max: Math.max.apply(Math, points)
        });
    }
}
```

This is a very verbose way to do it and you could probably collapse some of the logic. Also you would need to make sure you have data to check.

Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/gq6v77hx/5/).

Comment: This works like a charm! Though I have to tweak it a little to work: `entry.data` seems to be `[ ]`, and I noticed that my xData and yData are stored separately in `entry.xData` and `entry.yData`.

Comment: Correct, you would have to format your check in `theData.<your Y>` to match your data point format.